# Javascript Interop Dispose Problem with blazor serverside

Tags: c#, blazor, dispose, blazor-server-side, javascript-interop

When ever refresh or manually navigate to a Blazor page that is using javascript interop, it errors out because the dispose function no longer exists in javascript.

Is there a way to not run "dispose" on a component that implements IDisposable when its a refresh or a navigation?  Is there where the "ElementReference" type would help?

Here's some code for context:

My blazor component implements IDisposable:

```
@implements IDisposable
```

this runs my Dispose function, which calls on my interop file:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    JqxWindowJsInterop.Dispose();
}
```

my JsInterop runs this call to javascript:

```
public void Dispose()
    {
        jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>(
            "jqxWindowComponent.dispose",
            InstanceId);
        _JqxWindowJsInteropReference?.Dispose();
    }
```

which finally runs this in javascript:

```
window.jqxWindowComponent = {
dispose: function (instanceId) {
    console.log('jqxWindowComponent.dispose : ' + instanceId);
    if ($('#' + instanceId).length) {
        $('#' + instanceId).jqxWindow('destroy');
    }
    delete jqxWindowList[instanceId];       
}};
```

when I refresh or navigate to/from to this page through the browser I get this error

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'MyNameSpace.Components.JqxWindowComponent.JqxWindowJsInterop.get returned null.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is the instanceId?  Do you see if in the log files?  Did you check log file?

Comment: I assign my JavaScript components a generated guid, passed as InstanceId

Comment: Did you remove the instanceId?  Exception could be caused by the instance being deleted before the JaveScript is run.

Comment: The dispose removes the instance.  It runs correctly when navigating using the Blazor site, just crashes when navigating manually with the browser URL

Comment: You may have a timing issue and just lucky it doesn't crash when running.  The id may get deleted too early and you are only seeing issue when you step through slowly.

Comment: Right, I think I understand the problem, just not sure how to solve it.  If there was a PreNavigate in the Blazor life cycle I could solve it there

Comment: I think the issue is in the Java Dispose method.  You have an Async method that needs an await.

Comment: But the dispose from IDisposable isn’t async...

Comment: What about this : jsRuntime.InvokeAsync

Comment: I am using Async, the method itself shows up as null (again, only when manually navigating does the error happen, internal side navigation it disposes properly.

Comment: Async is not going to wait and continue executing.

Comment: I understand, I’m using the await.  The interop file is not there when it tries.

Comment: I think that confirm my suspicion that there is a race condition.  Where did the interop file get removed?

Comment: Looks like this is an open bug with microsoft: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26474

Comment: I do not see the correlation between your issue and the link you provided.  You have only one instance and just trying to delete.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74928714/9971404) for related issue and solutions.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this by adding a render check property.

```
private bool firstRenderComplete;
```

I set it here:

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if (firstRender)
    {
        firstRenderComplete = true;
        DayPilotJsInterop = new DayPilotJsInterop(JavascriptRunTime, InstanceId);

        await DayPilotJsInterop.Initialize();
    }
}
```

and finally test it here:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    if(firstRenderComplete == true)
    {
        DayPilotJsInterop.Dispose();
    }

}
```

Comment: to simplify you can just use if(firstRenderComplete) for true and if(!firstRenderComplete) for false.